# Cut out a part of Cell Value which starts with a specific string

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to cut out a part of a cell value.

This is how it should look:

[image]

So far I got this:

```
    For Each item In arr
    
    pos = InStr(item, "No")
    
    If pos > 0 Then
    
        ActiveSheet.Range("B" & row).Value = item
        row = row + 1
    
    Else
    
        ActiveSheet.Range("B" & row).Value = " N/A "
        row = row + 1
    
    End If
```

This returns me the rows but i still need to cut out the Values

-----Update-----

This is what i have now:

```
Sub cut()

Call Variables

    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim element2 As Variant
    Dim rows As Integer
    Dim rows2 As Integer
    
    arr = Array("test352532_No223", _
                "testfrrf43tw_No345figrie_ge", _
                "test123_No32_fer", _
                "test_Nhuis34", _
                "teftgef_No23564.345")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Numbers").Activate

    rows = 1
    rows2 = 1
        
    For Each element In arr
        
        Range("A" & rows).Value = element
 
        With regEx

            .Pattern = "(No[1-9][\.\d]+[a-z]?)"
            Set mc = regEx.Execute(element)

            For Each element2 In mc
                
                ActiveSheet.Range("B" & rows2).Value = element2
                rows2 = rows2 + 1

            Next element2
            
       End With
       
       rows = rows + 1
            
    Next element
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

And this is what it results:

[image]

So the problem is, that the Value in B4 should be in B5...

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("B" & row).Value = mid(item,pos)`?

Comment: ActiveSheet.Range("B" & row).Value = mid(item,pos)  this works but if there is a value like  testdewif_No234.erf  it should just display the No234 and not the entire

Comment: Include these kind of samples instead of oversimplified data. For example: Can `No` occur at the start of the string? Or is it always at then end if even present? Is there always a digit right behind it? Do you want to capture all alphanumeric character after `No`? What other cases can occur other than `.`? Be clear, be concise.

Comment: Yeah, thanks I've changed the Example. I just want the "No" with the following numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, test the next function:

```
Function extractNoStr(x As String) As String
  Dim frst As Long, last As Long, i As Long
  frst = InStr(1, x, "No", vbBinaryCompare)
  For i = frst + 2 To Len(x)
    If Not IsNumeric(Mid(x, i, 1)) Then last = i: Exit For
  Next i
  If i > Len(x) And last = 0 Then last = Len(x) + 1
    extractNoStr = Mid(x, frst, last - frst)
End Function
```

It can be tested as:

```
Sub testExtractNoStr()
   Dim x As String
   x = "test2345_No345figrie_ge"

   Debug.Print extractNoStr(x)
   Debug.Print activeCell.value 'select a cell containing such a string...
End Sub
```

To process all range of column A:A, returning in B:B, please use the next code:

```
Sub extractAll()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastR).Value2  'place the range in an array for faster processing
  ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1) 'ReDim the final array to receive all occurrences
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arrFin(i, 1) = extractNoStr(CStr(arr(i, 1)))
  Next i
  'drop the processed array content, at once:
  sh.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value2 = arrFin
End Sub
```

Comment: Displays en Error at the "arr" in  arrFin(i, 1) = extractNoStr(arr(i, 1))....                                 
ByRef argument type mismatch

Comment: @lemurdroid OK. I will adapt it. Since the function requires a string, the array may contain anything and I will adapt the code to correctly cast it. Adapted. Please, test it now and send some feedback.

Answer (score 4):

**Formula**:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=IFERROR("No"&-LOOKUP(1,-MID("_"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","|"),FIND("_No","_"&A1)+3,ROW($1:$99))),"")
```

**Notes**:

- Add leading `_` to allow for match at start of string;
- `FIND()` is case-sensitive;
- `SUBSTITUTE()` out the dot to prevent longer match with `FIND()`;
- The above will *not work well* when 1st digit after `No` is a zero.

---

**VBA**:

If VBA is a must, try an UDF, for example:

```
Function GetNo(s As String) As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = "^(?:.*?_)?(No\d+)?.*$"
    GetNo = .Replace(s, "$1")
End With

End Function
```

On your worksheets in `B1`, invoke through typing `=GetNo(A1)`.

Here I used regular expressions to 'cut' the substring you are after. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/n3fkht/1). The pattern means:

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(?:.*?_)?` - Optional non-capture group to match 0+ (Lazy) characters upto underscore. This would also allow `No` at start of string;
- `(No\d+)?` - Optional capture group to match `No` (case-sensitive) followed by 1+ digits;
- `.*` - 0+ Characters;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

**EDIT:** You can also call the function in your VBA-project:

```
Sub Test()

arr = Range("A1:A5").Value
            
For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    arr(x, 1) = GetNo(CStr(arr(x, 1)))
Next

Range("B1").Resize(UBound(arr)).Value = arr

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Already thought of regular expressions but I don't know how to output the matches so that If for example the Value in Cell A5 has no match that then B5 is blank and the next match is in B6

Comment: @lemurdroid, what do you mean with next match? Can a single string have multiple matches?

Comment: Please look in the post ( added an update ), i think you should understand

Comment: @lemurdroid, **1)** you have butchered the pattern as it does not at all do nomore what your desired results were in the top of your question. You now allow for decimals *and* alpha-chars. **2)** You have changed from `.replace()` to `.Execute()`. Why? This would now require a `.Test()` to avoid potential errors **and** you have to loop the match-object. That being said, it does not only require a match, it will therefor also skip the `rows2 + 1` part hence no gap inbetween your values. 3) As mentioned in the comment section above; be concise in how you phrase your question! Stop altering.

Comment: The Problem is that i have no idea how i should call the replace function

Comment: @lemurdroid, have you noticed my latest update?

Comment: Why does arr = Range("A1:A" & rows).Value not work? is it because the functions transfer parameter is a string ?

Comment: Yes @lemurdroid, that's right.

Comment: alright, thank you. now i just have to figure out how i do it with an array

Comment: @lemurdroid, It's literally there in my post.

Comment: If i copy your code, it does not work with arr = Range("A1:A" & rows).Value.

Comment: @lemurdroid I expected you would be able to change the code to your needs. Anyways, I edited ones more. You can edit in any other variables if need be.

Comment: I tried to change the regular expression to cut out the same part of these test674.re_test_no3243.ffe
test238.re_test_no1253e.jfe
unluckily unsuccessful :/ I think i don't get the part with the non-capturing group